# Timeshift doesn't start

Tags: backup, snapshot, timeshift

after I did backup my system with timeshift, but when I run `timeshift-launcher` in terminal it's not launching, and logs file is

```
[19:44:13] Session log file: /var/log/timeshift/2023-03-29_19-44-13_gui.log
[19:44:13] Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)
[19:44:13] DIST_ID: Ubuntu
[19:44:13] Main: check_dependencies()
[19:44:13] [Warning] Deleted invalid lock
[19:44:13] Main: add_default_exclude_entries()
[19:44:13] Main: add_default_exclude_entries(): exit
[19:44:13] update_partitions()
```

Looks like `update_partitions()` takes forever, did someone face same problem? Starting from menu and re-installing didn't help

Comment: Oh, I am facing the same problem with TimeShift. I think the problem is that snapshots are taking up a lot of memory for snapshots you don't see in GUI may be. I found old snapshots in my external hard under the snapshots folder, that I cannot even delete using sudo rm -rf command, which is disturbing. I don't know what to do to remove them.